# How to Send Data from Arduino to PC

Tags: c#, arduino, server, tcpclient, ethernet

I'm new to arduino.
I have a server side application (C# application) which responds on port 8888.
I have connected the Arduino with my Laptop using Ethernet.
My Laptop has a static IP address 192.168.1.23 and my Arduino has 192.168.1.22.
I can not connect to server side application.

I have the following Arduino Code

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 10, 0, 0, 177 };
byte server[] = { 192, 168, 1, 23 }; // Google

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    delay(1000);

    Serial.println("connecting...");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

    if (client.connect(server,8888)) {
        Serial.println("connected");
    } else {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know that your C# server application works correctly. If yes, add that information to your question, if no, add the server side code.

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: Yes Jan Doggen it's working correctly. When I make a PC client it works fine.. But it's not working when I use arduino as client.

Comment: @TobyAllen my program fails connection after reaching at 
if (client.connect(IPAddress(192,168,1,23),8888)) 
my server side application, running on pc having static ip 192.168.1.23, responds to port 8888

Answer (score 0):

You can checking that your connection is OK, try to ping the PC from the Ardunio or  a firewall blocking the messages? You can try this code

```
void loop()
{ 
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {

}
}
}
```

Comment: Fortan I want to make arduino client. my program fails connection after reaching at 
if (client.connect(IPAddress(192,168,1,23),8888)) 
my server side application, running on pc having static ip 192.168.1.23, responds to port 8888

Comment: I don't have any error.  My program jumps to else statement which is "Connection fail" . It is unable to establish connection.
if(client.connect(server,8888) not establishing connection.